# How to use Sentry Service in a NestJS App

Tags: nestjs, sentry

I am trying to use Sentry in a NestJS application.  I followed the instructions given on the Sentry site for setting up a NodeJS app to use Sentry without any success.  Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: There is an updated answer to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68831222/693737

Answer (score 0):

This package [NestJs Raven](https://github.com/mentos1386/nest-raven) can help you. It has a pretty straight forward documentation on there.