# Integrate nestjs with sentry

Tags: javascript, nestjs

I want to integrate sentry with nest.js + express but I just found raven version but that is deprecated.
I follow the sentry docs for integrate with express but dont know how to handle the  'All controllers should live here' part.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const Sentry = require('@sentry/node');

Sentry.init({ dsn: 'https://5265e36cb9104baf9b3109bb5da9423e@sentry.io/1768434' });

// The request handler must be the first middleware on the app
app.use(Sentry.Handlers.requestHandler());

**// All controllers should live here
app.get('/', function rootHandler(req, res) {
  res.end('Hello world!');
});**

// The error handler must be before any other error middleware and after all controllers
app.use(Sentry.Handlers.errorHandler());

// Optional fallthrough error handler
app.use(function onError(err, req, res, next) {
  // The error id is attached to `res.sentry` to be returned
  // and optionally displayed to the user for support.
  res.statusCode = 500;
  res.end(res.sentry + "\n");
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: It's not clear in your question, but for the code you've provided, does it have any problems other than not being integrated with nest.js?

Comment: all is fine just this part of the code is the problem app.get('/', function rootHandler(req, res) {
  res.end('Hello world!');
});

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For integrate sentry with nestjs we to follow this steps:

1. install npm i nest-raven
2. In main.ts

```
async function bootstrap() {
  Sentry.init({ dsn: 'https://5265e36cb9104baf9b3109bb5da9423e@sentry.io/1768434' });
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  // middlewares
  await app.listen(3000);
}
```

3. For use it to all controllers in app.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    RavenModule,...
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [{
    provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
    useValue: new RavenInterceptor({
      filters: [
        // Filter exceptions of type HttpException. Ignore those that
        // have status code of less than 500
        { type: HttpException, filter: (exception: HttpException) => 500 > exception.getStatus() },
      ],
    }),
  }],
})
```

The issue was tracking here https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/2269, there you can follow an example.

Answer (score 29):

I just created a Sample Project on Github to answer this question:

https://github.com/ericjeker/nestjs-sentry-example

Below is a partial copy of the README file. Let me know if you have any questions.

### Create the needed elements

Create Sentry module, service, and interceptor

```sh
$ nest g module sentry
$ nest g service sentry
$ nest g interceptor sentry/sentry
```

### SentryModule

Create the `SentryModule.forRoot()` method and add the `Sentry.init(options)` in it.

Call the `SentryModule.forRoot({...})` in the `AppModule` and integrate with your preferred configuration (I use `ConfigModule` and a `.env` file).

Add the call to the Express requestHandler middleware in the `AppModule.configure()`.

```js
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer): void {
    consumer.apply(Sentry.Handlers.requestHandler()).forRoutes({
      path: '*',
      method: RequestMethod.ALL,
    });
  }
```

It is important to use that middleware otherwise the current Hub will be global and
you will run into conflicts as Sentry creates a Hub by thread and Node.js is not multi-threaded.

### SentryService

We want to initialize the transaction in the constructor of the service. You can
customize your main transaction there.

Note that because I inject the Express request, the service must be request scoped. You
can read more about that [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes#request-provider).

```js
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class SentryService {
  constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) private request: Request) {
    // ... etc ...
  }
}
```

### SentryInterceptor

The `SentryInterceptor` will capture the exception and finish the transaction. Please also
note that it must be request scoped as we inject the `SentryService`:

```js
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class SentryInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(private sentryService: SentryService) {}

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    // ... etc ...
  }
}
```

As an example, I added a span. This is not necessary, but it will just make the trace nicer in the performance viewer of Sentry.

You can add more spans anywhere in your application simply by injecting the `SentryService` and calling `startChild` or by simply calling the `startChild` method of the current span.

Comment: This was an incredible answer. This is the way to go with Nest 8.

Comment: Great work! This line is giving me problems... 
`return Sentry.getCurrentHub().getScope().getSpan()`
Seems like the span created in the constructer just isn't available when we pull it from the service...

Comment: Follow up: Updated sentry SDK broke your example. Seems like the `createTransaction` method does not return the transaction anymore... downgrading to version 6.11 fixed the issue.

Comment: Hey @crice1988, thanks for pointing this out. For everyone else, it's a bug on Sentry's side, Sentry already merged a fix for it, but there is a workaround documented here: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/issues/4731#issuecomment-1078715187